# Why recv() from socket does not block

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, blocking, recv

I create a TCP server socket that listens to connect() requests and accept() them. After accepting a client socket receives data from it. I want recv() function to block with a timeout, but it seems to be non-blocking.

I have achieved the client to be in blocking mode when receiving response from the server, but it does not seem to work the same with the server side.

Below I copy-paste the server side that I want to receive data in blocking mode:

```
int clientSocket = accept(_serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)NULL, NULL);

if (clientSocket < 0)
    return -1;

// set TIMEOUT option to server socket
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 500 * 1000; 
int sockOptRet = setsockopt(clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv);

struct linger sl;
sl.l_onoff = 1;     /* non-zero value enables linger option in kernel */
sl.l_linger = 0;    /* timeout interval in seconds */
setsockopt(clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &sl, sizeof(sl));

char _rcvBuffer[sizeof(can_frame)];
int numBytesRcv = recv(clientSocket, _rcvBuffer, sizeof(can_frame), 0);
```

I have also tried it with MSG_WAITALL flag but it does not change anything...

Comment: How do you know it's not blocking? The return value and `errno` from a `recv` that is "non-blocking" versus one that is cut short by `SO_RCVTIMEO` is indistinguishable. The only way you could know that it's not blocking is by measuring the passage of time during the `recv` call. Have you done that? Half a millisecond is not long enough to be perceptible to a human.

Comment: I have used gettimeofday() function before and after recv() function and I disable send() funciton in client side, so there are no bytes to receive. And recv() returns zero bytes after a few microseconds. That's why I say that it's non-blocking...

Comment: Looking at kernel source, the timeout actually gets rounded up to the nearest HZ (clock tick, typically 1000) in `sock_set_timeout`. If your HZ is the same, that would be 1 HZ (or 1 millisecond). And note that one HZ is the finest granularity you'll get: The actual time spent blocking will vary, and 1 HZ basically means "until the next clock tick" which isn't necessarily a full millisecond (depending on when the `recv` call started, could be much less). Try increasing the timeout and see how long it blocks.

Comment: 1. When you say talk about 1ms time period you mean 1KHz (not 1Hz)
2. In my original code I have 500 * 1000 us = 500ms but I wrote it wrong here.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. Where I said "1 HZ"; I meant the length of time represented by a clock tick: [1 / HZ seconds] -- as you said, that's equivalent to 1KHz

Answer (score 0):

Your code should clearly block, but your timeout of 0.5s doesn't do showing it justice.

If you increase the timeout to something more conspicuous such as 2s and graft the code onto, e.g., [beej's tpc server template](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/server.c), you get something like:

```
/*
** server.c -- a stream socket server demo
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define PORT "3490"  // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10     // how many pending connections queue will hold

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    // waitpid() might overwrite errno, so we save and restore it:
    int saved_errno = errno;

    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);

    errno = saved_errno;
}


// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if (p == NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener


            // set TIMEOUT option to server socket
            struct timeval tv;
            tv.tv_sec = 2;
            tv.tv_usec = 0 * 500 * 1000; 
            int sockOptRet = setsockopt(new_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv, sizeof tv);

            struct linger sl;
            sl.l_onoff = 1;     /* non-zero value enables linger option in kernel */
            sl.l_linger = 0;    /* timeout interval in seconds */
            setsockopt(new_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &sl, sizeof(sl));

            char can_frame[1024];
            char _rcvBuffer[sizeof(can_frame)];
            int numBytesRcv = recv(new_fd, _rcvBuffer, sizeof(can_frame), 0); 



            if (send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now if your run this and then do:

```
nc localhost 3490
```

without typing a line to send, there should be a distinct 2-second wait
before the server gives up on you, indicating that the `recv` is indeed blocking.

Comment: I found out that the server was blocking indeed the first time recv() was called. But when the client was in recv() state in parallel with the server recv(), an RST signal was sent to server. And after that the server's receive timeout was being reset. Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: A `RST` is a packet containing the TCP `RST` flag; it indicates the target session is invalid or shutdown. I can't see any reason why that would happen while both client and server are blocked in `recv`. I think there's something else going on here that you're unaware of. Typically, an `RST` will be sent by the OS on one side when the *other* side sent data but the receiving socket was already closed.